# How to get random products if I don't have related products in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have an issue.  I want to show 4 related products in the product page.  That is simple and I have done that.   But if the product doesn't have any or has less than 4 products I want the remaining product to randomly appear in the page.

Comment: Randomly appear, but which products randomly appear? In the same category or another that you specified?

Comment: abnab what is the criteria of additional list?
Fast solution: check condition and then load more produts using standard magento collection.

Comment: I would say if it does not find any related products ...  list products of same category .. if thats not enough .list product of any catetory

Answer (score 2):

To select 4 random products first you need rewrite class that responsible for related block (or just move this file to local folder) and change logic for function that returns collection to something like next code:

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productsCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$productsCollection->getSelect()->limit(4);
```

Hope, it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in creating this functionality on the product page you can find most of the magic in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related::_prepareData()`.

To fill out your related products with random products, we first need to know exactly how many random products we'll need. In this case, it's (4 - related products found):

```
// Existing Magento code near end of method
$this->_itemCollection->load(); 

// Our code
$numRandomsToGet = 4 - count($this->_itemCollection);
```

Then we can fetch the appropriate number of random products and add them to the collection:

```
// Our code
$randCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($randCollection);
$randCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$randCollection->addStoreFilter();
$randCollection->setPage(1, $numRandomsToGet);
$randCollection->addIdFilter($this->_itemCollection->getAllIds(), true);

foreach($randCollection as $randProduct)
{
    $this->_itemCollection->addItem($randProduct);
}

// Existing Magento code
foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
    $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
}

return $this;
```

Caveat/Plug: I pulled this code from our [Related Products Manager extension for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12285/s/related-proudcts-manager-7301/) so there might be some fiddling external to this method that needs to get done but I don't think so. If you get stuck you can try downloading the extension and examining the code in its entirety. Or, of course, you can just use the extension as-is.